# Mapping for Indoor localization

Tags: java, android, mapping, indoor-positioning-system

I have developed and android app for indoor localization using Bluetooth beacon. I am getting the coordinates(which i have manually assumed for several reference point) as i move through the corridor of the building. I want to make a map of the corridor and insert those coordinates to the map so that the dot moves along the map as i change my position. Can somebody help me how to implement map on android and assign coordinates to it?
[Obtained Coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPNbu.jpg)

Comment: As you have already found coordinates, now you have to prepare map grid. You can assign the reference point in map.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some of the existing map services, like [OSM](https://www.openstreetmap.org/). It uses easy map structure (basically its xml file) and good map editor [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/). So you can easily create map of your location and assign your coordinates to display position.